# How can I hide certain Elements when taking a Screenshot

Tags: cocos2d-x, screenshot

In my project I've got a gameCamera which is used to diplay the things inside my level and a uiCamera which displays the ui-elements.
I'm trying to take a screenshot which only consists of the level-elements and not the ui.

My attempt was to hide the uiCamera which works but it also briefly hides the ui for the user and it doesn't look very nice.
This was the code:

```
// hide the camera
this->getUiCamera()->setVisible(false);

utils::captureScreen([](bool captureBool, std::string path) {
    // do something to make UI visible again, left this out because its not really relevant
}, "level_screenshot.png");
```

I also tampered around with renderTexture but that didn't work out well probably because of the parallax effect I use in the level.

Is there any way I can take a screenshot while hiding the uiCamera? Is it possible to take a Screenshot of only the gameCamera itself, maybe by using renderTexture?

My cocos version is 3.9

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding all the Nodes(which should not be present in the screenshot) in an Array, disable the visibility of all nodes just before taking the screen shot. Enable the visibility after the screen shot taken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried something similar in my example only that I was hiding a camera instead of the Nodes but the result is the same I assume. However this doesn't look good because the UI gets hidden for a few seconds and the user can notice it. I can't provide a solution either because we changed things a bit so we don't need to take screenshots anymore.